# How do I create and send Vcard (vcf) from Google Sheets?

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, vcf-vcard

I would like to send a Vcard to my email in attachment everytime someone fills out a form on our website. That way I can quickly add this contact to my phone (ios).

Right now we are using Zapier to import all form contact details in a spreadsheet - name, surname, email etc.

Now, I'd like to trigger some service to put those details in a Vcard and send it to me by email.

Is it possible to create a vcf file inside Google Sheets? Then I could send the link to this file to my email. Or there's some other service that creates Vcards and has API I could connect to Google Sheets?

Any other suggestion is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any mention of doing such thing in [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts).

However, try to checkout [CardDAV protocol](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/carddav/), it's the closest thing I find to what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Will try and let you know! :) Take care!